# C++ "unresolved external symbol" using namespace from different project

Tags: c++, namespaces, linker-errors

I have two projects (call them Test and Intrados).  Inside Intrados, I have the following namespace:

```
#include "Mapper.h"
#include "Director.h"
#include "Driver.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace IntradosMediator {
    void addVehicle(string);
}

void IntradosMediator::addVehicle(string vehicleName) {
    Mapper* mapper = Mapper::getInstance();
    mapper->addVehicle(vehicleName);
}
```

From within the Intrados project, calling "IntradosMediator::Mapper(addVehicle)" works just fine; yet, in project Test, the following code produces a link error:

```
#include "IntradosMediator.cpp"
#include "Mapper.h"
using namespace IntradosMediator;

int main(){
    IntradosMediator::addVehicle("Car X");
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Mapper *
 __cdecl Mapper::getInstance(void)" (?getInstance@Mapper@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in 
function "void __cdecl IntradosMediator::addVehicle(class std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" 
(?addVehicle@IntradosMediator@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@
std@@@Z)
```

I've made sure to add Intrados as a reference for Test, and also included it in the Include Directories.  Not sure what to do here, since I'm new to C++.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

**Edit:**
I'm adding the Mapper code here:

```
//.h
#ifndef MAPPER_H
#define MAPPER_H
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Mapper {
public:
    static Mapper* getInstance();
    void addVehicle(string);
private:
    //this is a singleton
    Mapper(){};
};
#endif

//.cpp
#include "Mapper.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


vector<string> vehicleList;

Mapper* Mapper::getInstance(){
    static Mapper instance;
    return &instance;
}

void
Mapper::addVehicle(string vehicleName) {
    vehicleList.push_back(vehicleName);
}
```

Comment: Is there a library associated with that function?

Comment: Why are you including a `.cpp`? This isn't normally done.

Comment: I did have my namespace as a .h, and also split between a .h and .cpp.  In each case I've had the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says the linker can't find `Mapper::getInstance` (it seems to find your `addVehicle` function just fine).  Might you be failing to include the library that implements "Mapper" in your link?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "library that implements 'Mapper'", could you elaborate?

Comment: I've tried out the code as it looks now, adding a main function that calls your getInstance function, and it compiles and links successfully (VC++2010).  I don't see how a link job that includes the object file produced from the .cpp file above could possibly produce that link error.  Is it possible that the .cpp above (presumable "Mapper.cpp") somehow isn't included in the project that Test.cpp is in?

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your code for class Mapper? 
It seems like you are missing addVehicle function in that class, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: unresolved external symbol "... Mapper::getInstance(void)" referenced in function "... IntradosMediator::addVehicle(...)" means the function that's missing is "Mapper::getInstance," not "IntradosMediator::addVehicle."